# Simplex algorithm with initial negative slack variables

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

I have the following LP problem:

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
min.  & & z = 2x+3y\\
\text{s.t. } & & x & \le 3\\
& & x & \ge 3\\
& & -x + 2y & \le -1\\
& & x, y & \ge 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}$$

I know this that the 2 first constraints are equivalent to $x = 3$, but I got some kind of theorotical question... If I add slack variables, I get the following:

$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
min.  & & z = 2x+3y\\
\text{s.t. } & & x + s_1 & = 3\\
& & -x + s_2 & = -3\\
& & -x + 2y + s_3 & = -1\\
& & x, y, s_1, s_2, s_3 & \ge 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}$$

Which gives me the following augmented matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\  
   0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
   0 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
   \hline
   1 & -2 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

From there, I have the following situation (which causes me some troubles... ):

1. There are no positive values in the objective row, so I should get the optimal solution.
2. The optimal solution includes only slack variables ($x=y=0$), but $s_2$ and $s_3$ are negative, actually this is not a feasible solution!

Here's my « question »: **What should I do when facing this case?**

As far as I know, I have a unfeasible solution if, when I pick a pivot column, I got only negative coefficients on it. Since I cannot pick one here, I don't know what to do...

Comment: Should the third row be 0 -1 2 0 0 1 -1?

Comment: @user3313320 Yes it should, edited, but the problem remains ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the variables are implicitly non-negative.

You initial basis is not primal feasible nor dual feasible. You need a 2 step simplex algorithm to get a feasible initial basis. See for example section 2 of http://math.jacobs-university.de/oliver/teaching/iub/spring2007/cps102/handouts/linear-programming.pdf

Comment: If I understood your link, once I got my second set of equations (with the slack variable), my choice of the basic variables is wrong (because it yields a non-feasible solution), so I should add artificial variables (like in the part 2 of your PDF)?

Comment: @holt: yes. That the general way to do it. In some particular cases, you can make shortcuts by applying dual steps or informed guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can combine the first two constraints to one constraint.

$\texttt{first and second constraint}$

$x\leq 3 $

$x\geq 3$

Combining the two constraints:

$x=3$

$\Rightarrow x^*=3$

Therefore the objective function is

$\texttt{min} \ \ z = 2\cdot 3+3y=6+3y$

$\texttt{third constraint}$

$-3 + 2y  \leq -1 \quad \quad |+3$

$2y\leq 2$

$y\leq 1$

Since the objective function has to be minimized and the coefficient of the y variable is positive, y has to be as small as possible. Therfore $y^*=0$, because $y\geq 0$.

And $z^*=6+0=6$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not looking to the solution to this problem which is kind of trivial, I want to know what is wrong with my simplex algorithm (since it should yield the same $z^*$ value but it doesn't, even with the 2 initials constraints).

Comment: First of all the RHS has to be positive. Therefore you have to multiply the second and the third constraint by -1. The (in-)equality signs are turning around.